# Google + Hamming (or binary) Search

Tags: algorithm, search, mapreduce, sql-execution-plan, hamming-distance

I've read here:

[How do search engines merge results from an inverted index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393781/how-do-search-engines-merge-results-from-an-inverted-index)

"query execution algorithms are actually fairly dumb"

and there are many sofisticated algorithms using Hamming distance that are supposed to be used in a search engine.

Those algorithms can be found in the papers:

Efficient Processing of Hamming-Distance-Based Similarity-Search Queries Over MapReduce.
HmSearch: an efficient hamming distance query processing algorithm.
Multi-Index Hashing: A data structure for fast exact nearest neighbor search in Hamming space.

Does anybody know if algorithms in Hamming Space is really useful?